# Read text in JTextArea into StringBuilder

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, stringbuilder

I try to read all lines in the text area into StringBuilder so that I can use the text in text area as a **whole string**. However I get the NullPointerException in line  **s.append(line);**. Why?

```
public class tu extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    JTextArea t;
    static StringBuilder s;

    tu (){

        setLayout(/*new BorderLayout()*/null);
        t=new JTextArea(30,77);
        JScrollPane s=new JScrollPane(t,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        JButton b=new JButton("process");
        b.addActionListener(this);
        JPanel p=new JPanel();
        JPanel p1=new JPanel();
        p.add(s);
        p.setBorder(new TitledBorder("sequence"));
        p.setBounds(0,0,880,540);
        p1.add(b);
        p1.setBounds(380,570,100,40);
        add(p);
        add(p1);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(900,700);
        setVisible(true);

    }
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
         String text=t.getText();
         while (text!=null){for (String line : text.split("\\n")){ 
         s.append(line);
         }}

     }


    public static void main(String[] args){
        tu t=new tu();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attempting to invoke any method on an object that has not been instantiated will result in an `NPE`. You need to instantiate your `StringBuilder` `s`:

```
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
```

Do you really want to wait until the user has clicked the `JButton` before building up the contents of this `StringBuilder`? `StringBuilders` are typically used as on-demand helper objects with local scope.

---

A number of things to note:

- Use of `static` member variables is considered poor design
- Class names start with uppercase letters
- Don't use absolute positioning(`null` layout). Use a [layout manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) instead
- The preferred approach is to create an instance of `JFrame` directly & use.
- The preferred approach for `ActionListeners` is to use either an anonymous instance or the [Action](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) interface.
- Consider using [initial threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)

Answer (score 1):

your StringBuilder is still null, when you want to write to it.

you need to instantiate your StringBuilder before appending.

```
s = new StringBuilder();
```

btw your StringBuilder s and your JScrollPane s have the same variable name, you should use different names.